# Strange Error in java permutation generating algorithm

Tags: java, runtime-error, permutation

My algorithm generates permutations of the number 0...n, where n can be any number from 1 to 9. it works perfectly for numbers from 1 to 8. But when I run it with 9, it runs for a while. Then suddenly aborts the process and exits... with no error message or any such thing! I have been coding in java for quite a while and have never experienced this error.

My algorithm:-

```
package utils;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class Lexicography {

    static ArrayList<Long> perms = new ArrayList<Long>();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        getPermutations(Integer.valueOf(args[0]));

        System.out.println("\nSize:-"+perms.size()+"\nTime:-"+(System.currentTimeMillis()-time));
        //This println is never printed... java aborts before that
    }

    public static ArrayList<Long> getPermutations(int num){
        int[] n = new int[num+1];
        for(int i=0; i<=num; i++) n[i]=i;
        perms.add(getLong(n));
        for(int i=num; i>=0; i--) permutate(n[i],n);
        return perms;
    }

    private static void permutate(int k, int[] n){
        if(k>n.length) return;
        int p=0;
        for(int i:n){ if(i==k) break; p++;}

        for(int i=0; i<n.length; i++){
            if(i==p || n[i]<k) continue;
            n=swap(p,i,n);
            perms.add(getLong(n));
            System.out.println("i:"+(i+1)+" k:"+k+"    n:"+getLong(n));//this prints all permutations till the last one and then poof!

            for(int j=k-1; j>=0; j--) permutate(j,n);
            n=swap(p,i,n);
        }
    }

    private static int[] swap(int i, int f, int[] a){
        int t=a[f];
        a[f]=a[i]; a[i]=t;
        return a;
    }

    private static long getLong(int[] n){
        long ten=1, num=0;
        for(int i=n.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            num+=n[i]*ten; ten*=10;
        }
        return num;
    }

}
```

Without the print statement, this runs pretty fast for numbers till 8 (for 8 it runs under 280ms). But for 9 it just stops suddenly after printing the last permutation. Can someone please help? Thank you!

Comment: It works for me.`Size:-3628800
Time:-104847`

Comment: Looks like it's a SIGSEGV: http://ideone.com/DeDNF7. I guess more than 3 million `Long`s takes up too much memory? See http://ideone.com/67764E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have a resource limited JVM and you are getting very close to the limit in the amount of memory you have.  Try running without printing but with `-verbosegc`  Creating a `List<Long>` is going to consume allot of memory which is only fine if you have plenty of free memory.

BTW I wouldn't print positive numbers with a `-` in front of them as they can look like negative numbers.  If I run on my machine, I see (without `-`)

```
Size: 3628800
Time: 18645
```

without printing

```
Size: 3628800
Time: 1420
```

with `-mx128m`

```
Size: 3628800
Time: 1894
```

with `-mx100m` it takes a very long time, to throw

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:577)
at Lexicography.permutate(Lexicography.java:31)
at Lexicography.permutate(Lexicography.java:34)
at Lexicography.permutate(Lexicography.java:34)
at Lexicography.permutate(Lexicography.java:34)
at Lexicography.permutate(Lexicography.java:34)
at Lexicography.permutate(Lexicography.java:34)
at Lexicography.getPermutations(Lexicography.java:19)
at Lexicography.main(Lexicography.java:9)
```

You are going to need at least a heap size of 128 MB to run this efficiently.

Comment: An alternative is to use `TLongArrayList` which wraps a `long[]` but given you can buy 32 GB for about $200, I would just use more memory.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with your code, it's with `System.out`, it can't display the amount of data you're giving it in a reasonable amount of time so it throws a hissy-fit. When I tried to run your application, it was still going after 6 minutes so I cancelled it, commented out the print statement, and ran it again, which took 2 seconds (according to my compiler) to output:

```
Size:-3628800
Time:-962
```

So I changed your code to instead print the data to a file, and ran it again, and it took 4 seconds to execute and created a nice 83.1 MB text file of the output. Here's the code I used (I'd change it to use less static things though):

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Lexicography
{
    static ArrayList<Long> perms = new ArrayList<>();
    private static BufferedWriter out;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        File outputFile = new File("output.txt");
        if(!outputFile.exists())
        {
            outputFile.createNewFile();
        }
        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile.getAbsolutePath()));
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        getPermutations(Integer.valueOf("9"));
        System.out.println("\nSize:-" + perms.size() + "\nTime:-" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
        out.close();
    }

    public static ArrayList<Long> getPermutations(int num) throws IOException
    {
        int[] n = new int[num + 1];
        for(int i = 0; i <= num; i++)
        {
            n[i] = i;
        }
        perms.add(getLong(n));
        for(int i = num; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            permutate(n[i], n);
        }
        return perms;
    }

    private static void permutate(int k, int[] n) throws IOException
    {
        if(k > n.length)
        {
            return;
        }
        int p = 0;
        for(int i : n)
        {
            if(i == k)
            {
                break;
            }
            p++;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < n.length; i++)
        {
            if(i == p || n[i] < k)
            {
                continue;
            }
            n = swap(p, i, n);
            perms.add(getLong(n));
            out.write("i:" + (i + 1) + " k:" + k + "    n:" + getLong(n) + "\n");
            for(int j = k - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                permutate(j, n);
            }
            n = swap(p, i, n);
        }
    }

    private static int[] swap(int i, int f, int[] a)
    {
        int t = a[f];
        a[f] = a[i];
        a[i] = t;
        return a;
    }

    private static long getLong(int[] n)
    {
        long ten = 1, num = 0;
        for(int i = n.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            num += n[i] * ten;
            ten *= 10;
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

Comment: On my laptop the problem still persists even if i run it without printing output.